# Passing arguments to an Assetic filter service from config.yml

Tags: symfony, assetic

I've written my own Assetic filter, contained within a Symfony2 Bundle, in order to compile CommonJS modules into a single file. It's called [cjsDeliveryBundle](https://github.com/mattcg/cjsDeliveryBundle), but let's leave that aside for now.

I want to be able to set different options on the filter from my `config_dev.yml` and `config_prod.yml` files.

The filter has a single public setter: `setMinifyIdentifiers`, which accepts a boolean. I read the Symfony2 documentation on [setter injection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#optional-dependencies-setter-injection) and added the following to my `config.yml`:

```
assetic:
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        cjs_delivery:
            resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/MattCG/cjsDeliveryBundle/Resources/config/services.xml"
            calls:
                - [ setMinifyIdentifiers, [ true ] ]
```

The following is the `services.xml` for my Bundle.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <parameters>
        <parameter key="matt_cg.cjs_delivery_filter.class">MattCG\cjsDeliveryBundle\Assetic\Filter\cjsDeliveryFilter</parameter>
        <parameter key="matt_cg.cjs_delivery_filter.minify_identifiers">null</parameter>
    </parameters>

    <services>
        <service id="matt_cg.cjs_delivery_filter" class="%matt_cg.cjs_delivery_filter.class%">
            <tag name="assetic.filter" alias="cjs_delivery"></tag>
            <call method="setMinifyIdentifiers">
                <argument>%matt_cg.cjs_delivery_filter.minify_identifiers%</argument>
            </call>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

The filter works fine, except that the setter is never called with `true` as an argument. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. The solution is to have separate YAML parameters files for each environment and to specify the filter parameters in each one.

So here's what I did in my case.

1. Remove the `- { resource: parameters.yml }` from the `imports:` directive in `config.yml`.
2. Remove the `parameters.yml` file and put the parameters in two new files instead: `parameters_dev.yml` and `parameters_prod.yml`.
3. Add `- { resource: parameters_dev.yml }` to the `imports:` directive in `config_dev.yml` and `- { resource: parameters_prod.yml }` to the `imports:` directive in `config_prod.yml`.
4. Add `matt_cg.cjs_delivery_filter.minify_identifiers: true` to the `parameters:` directive in `parameters_prod.yml`.